# How To Access Callback Like in setState from useState Hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Has anyone managed to create a sync callback for the update piece of the useState hook in react 16.8? I have been looking for one so that I can deal with synchronous actions with a 3rd party library and I can't seem to make one work for my needs.

If anyone has any references to people that have successfully completed this please add them here.

Cheers,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With hooks, you no longer need a callback from the `setState` function. Now, you can set state with the `useState` hook, and listen for its value to update with the `useEffect` hook. The optional second parameter of the `useEffect` hook takes an array of values to listen to for changes. In the example below, we are just monitoring one value for changes:

```
const Example = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // do something when value changes
  }, [value]);

  return (
    <button onClick={() => setValue('Clicked!')}>
      Click Me!
    </button>
  );
};
```

Read more about the `useEffect` hook [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect).

Answer (score 3):

You can use useEffect/useLayoutEffect to achieve this:

```
const SomeComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0)

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (count > 1) {
      document.title = 'Threshold of over 1 reached.';
    } else {
      document.title = 'No threshold reached.';
    }
  }, [count]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count}</p>

      <button type="button" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Increase
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If you are looking for an out of the box solution, check out [this custom hook](https://github.com/the-road-to-learn-react/use-state-with-callback) that works like useState but accepts as second parameter a callback function:

```
import useStateWithCallback from 'use-state-with-callback';

const SomeOtherComponent = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useStateWithCallback(0, count => {
    if (count > 1) {
      document.title = 'Threshold of over 1 reached.';
    } else {
      document.title = 'No threshold reached.';
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{count}</p>

      <button type="button" onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>
        Increase
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

It can be installed via `npm install use-state-with-callback`

**If you want to make synchrone layout updates, use `import { useStateWithCallbackInstant } from 'use-state-with-callback';` instead.**