# Missing a comma in changing my CLASS code to FUNCTIONAL code

Tags: react-native

I am having trouble when trying to convert this function from a Class based one to a Functional based one. In the _spring() i seem to have an issue using the useState() within the context of an Animated component.

**CLASS Style**

```
 constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.springValue = new Animated.Value(100);
    }

 state = {
        currentIndex: 1,
        backClickCount: 0,
    }
 componentDidMount() {
        BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton.bind(this));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        BackHandler.removeEventListener('hardwareBackPress', this.handleBackButton.bind(this));
    }

    handleBackButton = () => {
        this.state.backClickCount == 1 ? BackHandler.exitApp() : this._spring();
        return true;
    };

 _spring() {
        this.setState({ backClickCount: 1 }, () => {
            Animated.sequence([
                Animated.spring(
                    this.springValue,
                    {
                        toValue: -.07 * height,
                        friction: 5,
                        duration: 300,
                        useNativeDriver: true,
                    }
                ),
                Animated.timing(
                    this.springValue,
                    {
                        toValue: 100,
                        duration: 300,
                        useNativeDriver: true,
                    }
                ),
            ]).start(() => {
                this.setState({ backClickCount: 0 });
            });
        });
    }
```

My attempt at moving it to **FUNCTIONAL** style is:

```
 const [currentIndex, setCurrentIndex] = useState(1);
    const [backClickCount, setBackClickCount] = useState(0);

    const springValue = new Animated.Value(100);

 const handleBackButton = () => {
        backClickCount == 1 ? BackHandler.exitApp() : _spring();
        return true;
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        const backHandler = BackHandler.addEventListener(
            "hardwareBackPress",
            () => {
                handleBackButton();
            }
        );
        return () => backHandler.remove(); 
    }, []);

     const _spring = () => {**
         setBackClickCount(1), () => {
            Animated.sequence([
                Animated.spring(
                    springValue,
                    {
                        toValue: -.07 * height,
                        friction: 5,
                        duration: 300,
                        useNativeDriver: true,
                    }
                ),
                Animated.timing(
                    springValue,
                    {
                        toValue: 100,
                        duration: 300,
                        useNativeDriver: true,
                    }
                ),
            ]).start(() => {
                setBackClickCount(0)
            });
        });
    }
```

I've lost a comma in making the transition (see the **). How should this function look, as i feel like i'm very close. Would it be better to put it in a useEffect()? If so, how?

Comment: This might help to answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55026970/how-to-access-callback-like-in-setstate-from-usestate-hook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `class` component you are using the `callback` function for the `setState` function of a react `state`.

This is for the following usecase.

> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater, callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update has been applied

This second callback argument of the `setState` function was removed for the `useState` hook for react functional components. However, you can use a `useEffect` with the state as a dependency in order to react on state changes which will guarantee that the `state` already contains the updated value. This is by design of the framework and is recommended [here in the official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html).

In your case, you must be very careful! You are setting the same state `backClickCount` in your callback function again (in the start callback). If we just use the same code in a `useEffect` and react on `backClickCount` changes, then this would be an infinite loop. Thus, we must guard this. Since you are setting `backClickCount` equal to one in the `_spring` function, then start the animation, and then set the `backClickCount` back to zero, we can guard this in the `useEffect` with a simple `if statement` in order to prevent an infinite loop. `If backClickCount` is equal to zero, do something, set the state to zero. This will fire the useEffect again but this time it won't run again.

That being said, we can translate your missing code of your functional component as follows.

```js
const [backClickCount, setBackClickCount] = useState(0);

React.useEffect(() => {
 if (backClickCount === 1) {
   Animated.sequence([
        Animated.spring(
           springValue,
              {
                 toValue: -.07 * height,
                 friction: 5,
                 duration: 300,
                 useNativeDriver: true,
               }
           ),
        Animated.timing(
              springValue,
                 {
                   toValue: 100,
                   duration: 300,
                   useNativeDriver: true,
                 }
        ),
     ]).start(() => {
          setBackClickCount(0)
      });
   });
  }
}, [backClickCount])

const _spring = () => {
   setBackClickCount(1)
}
```

**Remarks:** Some explanation if you are unfamiliar with `useEffect`. The `useEffect` takes two arguments. A function and an array. The array holds the `dependencies` of the hook. If one of the values inside the dependency array changes, the function provided will be called. Thus, if the states value is updated, it will be fired. This enables us to perform side effects on a state change. A common pitfall in react are infinite loops using this pattern. Usually this occurs if we set a state inside the `useEffect` and have its state value inside the dependency array of the same `useEffect`. If we do not guard this properly, this will lead to an infinite loop.

If the dependency array is empty, then the `useEffect` will be called exactly once `onMount` of the react component.